# player size with different Zoom

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have got many videos from youtube for soccer players, So I need to estimate the player size with different zoom in various videos.

I know the player height is around 185cm, then if we assume that the height of far player (zoom out) is 185 and make it the stander case to depend on it, then we can estimate the player height at different zoom, if it is zoom in more than the stander case then the height is larger than 185cm, But I don't have any information about the focal length or distance to player.

How can I make a proper estimation at different zoom, with assuming a stander case?

Answer (score 0):

1. **I do not think you can measure the Player height and also using presumptions on the height the same time.**

   because in that way you presume the height is avg 185 cm so the measurement gets you the same value. Instead you can isolate more then one players in standing pose (the more the better), create average `z` distance from camera map (assuming the players are 185cm in height). Interpolate / smooth between measured grid points, filter out inconsistencies and then from it compute the player height again.
2. **more precise would be to lock onto some known object size**

   for example I think the rail is unified size. If it is captured from a slight angle you can estimate the camera frustrum and compute the Z-map or camera parameters more precisely.

   Another superb object is the ball (on the ground)... so you can obtain zoom at 2 different distances from camera and we know the ground is flat. So you can try to compute the ground plane equation parameters + camera distortion for the whole image ...
3. **if you have hi-resolution video stream**

   then may be even better would be to detect steps (during run near predefined speed) while walking the average step distance for most people (almost regardless on height) is 70-75 cm. So detect that for player you want to measure and you can obtain the zoom of him directly ... So the height measurement should be much more accurate

   Also if you know the race of the player you can lock on to more racial average features like head size,arm/leg size ratio, etc... there are studies for that...

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the videos are given to me, I got them from Youtube. then I have to make assumption to estimate the height, please could you see this question for details [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764609/estimate-pixel-cm-for-object-with-different-zoom)

Comment: @Hanaa I already did,... I assume those players are from the same image in that case you can focus on the ball ... player near it is easy measure the pixel size of ball and compute scale by `pixels2cm=mall_size_cm,/ball_size_pixel`. If you got animation you can set all scales per screen position (where the ball travels on the ground) and interpolate the missing areas... that would give you scale map (analogical to depth(Z)-map) so you would know the scale per each pixel ... then just measure pixel size of player and multiply by scale in that area ...